# Are й and ь exceptions to letters named after pronunciation?

Tags: граматика

Through my studies I have come across the letter 'Ь' for soft sign and the letter 'й' for iot. I wonder now if there are more named letters within the Ukrainian language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows zero research effort. A trivial search for Wikipedia [quickly reveals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_alphabet#Letter_names_and_pronunciation) the entire alphabet and the names of all letters

Comment: How can I improve this question, since I do not wish to keep it if it is rated negatively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every letter has a name.

But the fact is that names of the most of the Ukrainian letters simply resemble their pronunciations more or less:

- Names of vowel-like letters exactly resemble their pronunciation as when the letter is used in the beginning of the word, e.g.: *а* is called *а* /ɑ/, *я* is called *я* /jɑ/, etc.
- Names of consonant-like letters are typically extended with *а* /ɑ/ (put after the corresponding consonant) or *е* /ɛ/ (put after or before the consonant), e.g:

  - *к* (produces /k/ sound) is called *ка* /kɑ/;
  - *л* (produces /l/ sound) is called *ел* /ɛl/;
  - *з* (produces /z/ sound) is called *зе* /zɛ/.

So far the only Ukrainian letters that don't follow that scheme are *й* (produces /j/ sound, but is called *йот* /jɔt/ (not /jɑ/, /ɛj/ or /jɛ/ as one may expect when looking on the other consonants)) and *ь* (produces no sound (modifies preceding letter's sound), is called *м'який знак* /mjɑˈkɪj ˈznɑk/, which literally means “soft sign”).

Answer (score 3):

*Just for notice to answer of Sasha and about not obviously things.*

Sasha writed about their *sound* for reading alphabet. What is it meaning? When to write here is just *к* — not *ка*, but when reading, here is *ка*. So, each letter is already name themself.

Another thing, Ukrainian has genders, and each name of letters is in neuter gender but has not cases. So, correct writing is *велик**е** [к](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=39757&page=1257)*.

Sasha writed about variation sounds. But here is nothing hard, because currently sounds are just coppied from [Classic Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_alphabet#Classical_Latin_alphabet), even for different sounds but with similar way of pronunciation. Let’s look.

```
   Same         Different Sound
C  Sound  L     C       L

Б   be    B  →  В  we         — from Greek beta
Г   ɦе    G  →  Ц  tse  C  ke — from Greek gamma
Ґ   ɡe    ┘     Ч  tʃe  ┘ 
Д   de    D     Х  xa   H  ha
К   ka    K     З  ze   Z  dzeta
Л   el    L
M   em    M     Only Cyrrilic just remember
Н   en    N     Ж  ʒe
П   pe    P     Ш  ʃа   ┐
Р   er    R     Щ  ʃtʃa ┘
С   es    S
Т   te    T     Only with Greek
Ф   еf    F     Й  jot  J      — from Greek iota
```

Only one consonant left — *й* which represent the sound *j* and *short i* which came from *i* which is from Greek iota. Obviously, we cann’t sound that as as *ja* or *je*, because in this case we get *я* and *є*. So we and others Slovs (for Cyrillic [*ј*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serbian_Cyrillic_alphabet) or *j* if Latin script) use just Greek name here.

Letter *ь* is even non-letter but *sign*, that is why is called as *soft sign*. For example, Serbian remove *ь* and created letters as *љ*, *њ*. For Ukrainian need many another letters, so *ь* is saved here.

Comment: ah.. ok. дякуююю

Comment: I have upvoted, although it is not recorded by those with less than 15 reputation.

Comment: I recommend update question. Example: why _й_ and _ь_ donʼt sound as all another letters. And why currently letters of Cyrillic doesnʼt sound as Old Cyrillic where almost each letter has own name.

Comment: I have changed the title now, is it more suited.